# How to SELECT by an array in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have an table like this:

```
DROP TABLE tmp;
CREATE TABLE tmp (id SERIAL, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (5, 'five');  
SELECT id, name FROM tmp;
```

It's like this:

```
 id | name  
----+-------
  1 | one
  2 | two
  3 | three
  4 | four
  5 | five
(5 rows)
```

Then I have an array of `ARRAY[3,1,2]`. I want to get query the table by this array, so I can get an array of `ARRAY['three', 'one', 'two']`. I think this should be very easy but I just can't get it figured out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the array order, it needs to be unnested with the index order (using `row_number()`), then joined to the `tmp` table:

```
SELECT array_agg(name ORDER BY f.ord)
FROM (
  select row_number() over() as ord, a
  FROM unnest(ARRAY[3, 1, 2]) AS a
) AS f
JOIN tmp ON tmp.id = f.a;

    array_agg
-----------------
 {three,one,two}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking it should be much more easier, as this seems a very common use case for array isn't it?

Comment: `generate_subscripts` can also be used to get the array subscripts, but it wouldn't make it much simpler. There's a good related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number

Answer (score 0):

Use `unnest` function:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tmp
WHERE id IN (SELECT unnest(your_array));
```

There is a different technique as suggested by Eelke:
You can also use the `any` operator

```
SELECT id, name FROM tmp WHERE id = ANY ARRAY[3, 1, 2];
```

Comment: You can also use the any operator `SELECT id, name FROM tmp WHERE id = ANY ARRAY[3, 1, 2];`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the array as output then try this:

SELECT array_agg(name) FROM tmp WHERE id = ANY (ARRAY[3, 1, 2]);

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3b32a/7)